Using ClsModule to inject proxy class in NestJS, Proxy comes up empty
I have a NestNS module that's importing ClsModule like so:
@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [
    //... some other providers, not related
    AuthZService,
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    ClsModule.forFeatureAsync({
      provide: REQUEST_PROXY, // <-- Some constant I defined
      inject: [CLS_REQ],
      useFactory: (request: Request) => {
        return {
          req: request,
        };
      },
      global: true, // <-- Not sure if this is needed, I've tried both ways
    }),
  ],
  exports: [AuthZService],
})

Then, I'm trying to use that proxy in AuthZService which looks like this:
@Injectable()
export class AuthZService {
  constructor(
    // ... Some other stuff that works
    @Inject(REQUEST_PROXY) private readonly requestProxy: { req: Request },
  ) {}

  private get clsRequest(): ProfileRequest {
    return this.requestProxy.req;
  }

  // ...

The code compiles and the service starts up, however if I set a breakpoint at return this.requestProxy.req; I see:

Basically it appears the injected object is "empty" and doesn't contain what was produced in useFactory.  In fact, if I set a breakpoint at:
      useFactory: (request: Request) => {
        return { // <--- Breakpoint
          req: request,
        };
      },

The breakpoint is never even hit.  Any ideas on what's going on?
BTW - My goal here is to inject the current Request object into a service that is not Request scoped, nor do I want to make it Request scoped.  I just need access to a proxy that can give me access to the current request.  If there's a better way to do that, I'd love to hear it.

I do some research to achieve your goal and here is a step-by-step solution:
1- Install Dependencies:
npm install nestjs-cls

2- Create a Request Proxy Module:
Create a module to handle the request proxy provider.
// request-proxy.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

export const REQUEST_PROXY = 'REQUEST_PROXY';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: REQUEST_PROXY,
      useFactory: (req: Request) => ({ req }),
      inject: [REQUEST],
    },
  ],
  exports: [REQUEST_PROXY],
})
export class RequestProxyModule {}

3- Middleware for Request Context
Implement middleware to manage request context using nestjs-cls.
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { ClsService } from 'nestjs-cls';

@Injectable()
export class ClsMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private readonly clsService: ClsService) {}

  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    this.clsService.run(() => {
      this.clsService.set('req', req); // Store the request object
      next();
    });
  }
}

4- Inject Request Proxy into Service:
Finally, inject the REQUEST_PROXY provider into your service to access the current request object.
// authz.service.ts
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { REQUEST_PROXY } from './request-proxy.module';

@Injectable()
export class AuthZService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(REQUEST_PROXY) private readonly requestProxy: { req: Request },
  ) {}

  private get currentRequest(): Request {
    return this.requestProxy.req;
  }

  public logRequestInfo() {
    console.log(this.currentRequest); // Logs the current request object
  }
}

5- Include Modules in AppModule:
Import RequestProxyModule and ClsMiddleware into your AppModule to make them available throughout your application.
    // app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ClsModule } from 'nestjs-cls';
import { RequestProxyModule } from './request-proxy.module';
import { ClsMiddleware } from './cls.middleware';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      // Your TypeORM configuration
    }),
    ClsModule.forFeatureAsync({
      provide: REQUEST_PROXY,
      useFactory: (clsService: ClsService) => {
       return {
        provide: REQUEST_PROXY,
        useFactory: () => {
         const req = clsService.get('req');
         return { req };
        },
       };
     },
     inject: [ClsService],
    }),
    RequestProxyModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
consumer
  .apply(ClsMiddleware)
  .forRoutes({ path: '*', method: RequestMethod.ALL });
}}

Explanation:
    RequestProxyModule: Provides a proxy mechanism (REQUEST_PROXY) to inject the current request object across services without making them Request scoped.

ClsMiddleware: Middleware that ensures the current request object is stored using nestjs-cls, making it accessible throughout the request lifecycle.

AuthZService: Injects REQUEST_PROXY to access the current request object (req) in a service that is not Request scoped.


Yea, that's fairly similar to what I have right now.  We were hoping to avoid ClsModule.forRoot() and adding the module globally, as we want the storage "scoped" to a certain set of services.

Oh, if you don't need it globally, you can just use ClsModule.forFeature() instead. This way, you can scope the storage to specific modules or services without affecting the whole app. Just swap out ClsModule.forRoot() for ClsModule.forFeature() in your imports

If you update your answer with working code, I'll award the bounty..  Thanks!

thanks!! in fact when I saw your comment I updated the answer.

Thanks!  With your code, the service starts up without any errors.  However, I have the same problem as I did originally.  The injected REQUEST_PROXY object is just an empty proxy that has never been initialized.

so in your AuthZService the this.requestProxy.req is undefined? because when I inject authZService in a XService and I run this.authZService.logRequestInfo() that run clsRequest() successfully with the req object

Sorry I could never get this working, but seeing how no one else had any ideas I'll award the bounty..  Most likely there's something else going on in the app, who knows..
